# SSRS Showing three Dots On Legend

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

On `SSRS` Pie chart legend is showing three dots if data in legend is more then the height of chart, but if i am clicking on the dots i am not able to navigate to other options in the legend.

[image]

Please help me Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to intuition, the ellipsis mean that there are more items but the list **doesn't** expand.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239321.aspx)

> By default, the legend is formatted as a list of one or more rows
>   containing one legend item each. The legend area expands to
>   accommodate the number of legend items. **If the legend cannot expand,
>   an ellipsis (…) is displayed.** Depending on the specified legend style,
>   the legend can expand vertically or horizontally. You can change the
>   layout style on the Legend Properties dialog box or change the
>   allocated space to display all the legend items.

Comment: is it possible to make the legend scrollable?  Asking because I would like to keep the legend the same size, but still allow all of the fields to be seen